# why String in java does not override readObject?

Tags: java, serialization, immutability

I was studying effective java and In immutability(Item 15) it is written that:
Make defensive copies (Item 39) in constructors, accessors, and **readObject** methods (Item 76).

And In Item 76 It is advised to override readObject and create a defensive copy of the mutable object by compromising **final** keyword. So i checked the String class in java and check whether they have done the same for `final char value[];` but readObject is not overridden.

I am confused about this ? Please if answer.

Comment: One thing to note:  `String` is just a wrapper around a `char` array.  It's not like the example in Item 76 where there's special validation going on of the `Date` instances (i.e. in the example, `end` has to be greater than `start`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but char[] is also a mutable state right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings, arrays and enums are special cases in serialization, and are not serialized through readObject/writeObject like other Objects are.

Here is the comment from [String.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html):

```
   /**
    * Class String is special cased within the Serialization Stream Protocol.
    *
    * A String instance is written initially into an ObjectOutputStream in the
    * following format:
    * <pre>
    *      <code>TC_STRING</code> (utf String)
    * </pre>
    * The String is written by method <code>DataOutput.writeUTF</code>.
    * A new handle is generated to  refer to all future references to the
    * string instance within the stream.
    */
```

and here are the special cases from [ObjectOutputStream.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java.html):

```
// remaining cases
if (obj instanceof String) {
    writeString((String) obj, unshared);
} else if (cl.isArray()) {
    writeArray(obj, desc, unshared);
} else if (obj instanceof Enum) {
    writeEnum((Enum) obj, desc, unshared);
} else if (obj instanceof Serializable) {
    writeOrdinaryObject(obj, desc, unshared);
} else {
    if (extendedDebugInfo) {
        throw new NotSerializableException(
            cl.getName() + "\n" + debugInfoStack.toString());
    } else {
        throw new NotSerializableException(cl.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`readObject` should be used when deserializing an object that has non transient fields that require a special handling. String is serializable and doesn't have such fields so it's not relevant to it.

As for defensive copy, since Strings are immutable - you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Item 76 OP refers to is writing readObject defensively so that you e.g. can't create a String whose starting `int offset` is outside of its `char[] value`. String instead protects against this by being a special case in serialization.